# Segue won't perform due to this error "Receiver (<ViewController: ) has no segue with identifier" but segue is identified

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have been getting this same error all day and I understand that it is saying that the segue is not identified in storyboard, but it is. Below is the code I believe is relevant: 
1.IBAction for the button that is signaling for the segue.

```
-(IBAction)launchScanner:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"launch Scanner pressed");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"launchScanner" sender:self];     
}
```

2. This is the prepare for segue function, I've left it empty for now, not sure if I need to include something in it.

   ```
   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"launchScanner"]){  

   }   
   }
   ```
3. I had originally made everything programatically, here is how I instantiated the Navigation Controller (this is in appdelegate.m):

   ```
   ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
   _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   _window.rootViewController = navigationController;
   [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```
4. Also Here are pictures of my storyboard setup and proof that the segue is identified[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfPLL.png)[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNnCT.png)

Comment: If you aren't creating your view controller from the storyboard then it isn't associated with a scene and therefore it isn't associated with any segues.

Comment: Also, just instantiating the views modally has been working perfectly, the issue is only when I'm trying the push segues with the navigation controller.

Comment: so I should be instantiating the initial view controller or the destination view controller from storyboard, or both? and where would I do that? the initial one in app delegate and then the destination view controller in prepare for segue? or in the IBAction method itself?

Comment: In my opinion, If you are going to use a storyboard you may as well do everything from the storyboard.  Simply set the navigation controller as your initial scene and remove the code from AppDelegate.

Comment: I can't help you without more information - the scenes in your storyboard are blank!

Comment: Ok so removed the appdelegate code and it works thank you so much

Comment: yeah it's because I set up all the UI programatically. but thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to instantiate your nav controller programmatically, you need to get a reference to it from the storyboard. You can use this if you need to perform some function in the app delegate before loading the initial VC.

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *initialNavVc = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialNavVc;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your Storyboard.
Navigation Controller should be "Intial View Controller."
Please check highlight in your image [image: here]

Here is the solution to tha corrected Storyboard image[image]